# Error exceptions.IndexError while importing in Odoo products

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to import 8500 products, and I cut the CSV in files with 1000 rows. Everything goes fine, but when I get 2500, I get this error:

Unknown error during import: : list index out of range at row 2

```
name,categ_id,standard_price,list_price,Public Price,default_code,description_purchase,Main Supplier,sale_delay,taxes_id,Id. Externo,property_account_expense,route_ids/id,Acabado,product_variant_ids/attribute_line_ids/attribute_id,product_variant_ids/attribute_line_ids/value_ids
Mueble Base Encajonada con Estante Metal,Category / Subcategory,999.00,999.24,999.24,A037073000,MOBILETTO BASE SCATOLATA,Provider,35,IVA 21%,A037073000,400000080,"purchase.route_warehouse0_buy,stock.route_warehouse0_mto",A03,Color,D7
```

Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error came because of you are given extra line value compare to columns label.

For example:

You have 16 columns than you must have to give 16 values. If you give 17 values than this type of error will come `list index out of range`

Situation:

Please recheck columns value it must be same as the number of columns label.

Comment: Yes you are correct, But in that line, might be you filled extra. While we are copy data and paste on csv file. For example we copy 15 columns and paste on csv file, sometime it will paste data in 17 columns because of some special char. Please check twice columns value.